# How can I authenticate with YoutubeService using the OpenID login?

Tags: grails, spring-security, openid

I am using Grails and I want to manipulate my playlist from YouTube. I can't find a method to connect to the Youtube API using the OpenID user. Is there a way to manipulate my YouTube data by loggin in with an OpenID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grails **[Spring Security OpenId](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid)** plugin, which depends on the excellent **[Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)** plugin should provide what you're looking for.

Comment: I am using that plugin and it doesn't really help. But from what i am reading [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/) OAuth is what i should have used.